# %s with adding new dictionary item

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a log in/sign up system, and I am trying to make it set a dictionary value when you sign up, by using a dictionary index with the new user's name but I cannot get it to work. I try using

```
logininfo['%s_username']%(newuser_name) = str(newuser_username)
```

but it just doesn't work. It says

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Project_1.py", line 22
logininfo['%s_username']%(newuser_name) = str(newuser_username)
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Comment: logininfo['%s_username'%(newuser_name)] = str(newuser_username)

Comment: as xnx and kevins answers are correct, another way is `logininfo[newuser_name + "_username"] = str(newuser_username)` your question is more of a "How do i concatenate strings" question, than a dictionary related question.

Answer (score 3):

Move the `%` and argument inside the brackets.

```
logininfo['%s_username' % newuser_name] = str(newuser_username)
```